# Get error while using extend-chrome/messages while sending messgae from background script to content script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am using [this](https://github.com/extend-chrome/messages) library for messaging.

I have my background script like this

```js
import { sendUrlInfo, waitForUrl } from 'utils/messaging';
import URL from 'url-parse';

chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener((details) => {
  const url = new URL(details.url);
  console.log('sending', url.hostname, url.pathname);
  sendUrlInfo(new URL(details.url));
});

chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener((details) => {
  if (details.url !== 'about:blank') {
    const url = new URL(details.url);
    console.log('sending', url.hostname, url.pathname);
    sendUrlInfo(new URL(details.url));
  }
});
```

And according to documentation i have message.js as shown below

```js
import { getMessage } from '@extend-chrome/messages';
import URL from 'url-parse';

const messageTypes = {
  URL_INFO: 'URL_INFO',
};

export const [sendUrlInfo, urlStream, waitForUrl] = getMessage<URL>(
  messageTypes.URL_INFO,
);
```

and now content script I have written in react
So i am trying to subscribe to stream when the component is mounted

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import Editor from 'content/components/Editor';
import Opener from 'content/components/Opener';
import { urlStream, waitForUrl } from 'utils/messaging';

const Main: React.FC = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false);

  const editorRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('MOunted');
    urlStream.subscribe(([url]) => {
      console.log('Received', url.hostname, url.pathname);
      if (url.hostname === 'www.youtube.com' && url.pathname === '/watch') {
        if (!showContent) setShowContent(true);
      } else {
        if (showContent) setShowContent(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyPress);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyPress);
    };
  });

  const onKeyPress = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 192) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    }
  };

  if (!showContent) return <></>;

  return (
    <>
      <div>test</div>
      <Opener isOpen={isOpen} onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)} />
      <Editor
        isOpen={isOpen}
        ref={editorRef}
        onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

The error I am getting in background script console is

> Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

I think as much as i understand the background script is trying to send msg but the content script observable is not subscribed yet. As content script run after the page is loaded.
If this is the issue is there any way to use this library properly.

BTW this works if we use normal chrome api like this

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
        tabs[0].id,
        message,
        function () {
                console.log("msg sent")     
        }
    );
});
```

and use onMessage to receive the msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background page needs to know that we're sending a message to a tab. Unless `options.tabId` is defined, `sendUrlInfo` sends a message using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

Add the options argument to `sendUrlInfo` in the background script:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener((details) => {
  const url = new URL(details.url);
  console.log('sending', url.hostname, url.pathname);

  const options = { tabId: details.tabId }; // Add options.tabId here
  sendUrlInfo(new URL(details.url), options);
});
```